# Memory process is using

Tags: memory-usage

I want to determine via cli how much memory seamonkey is using.

I know pidof seamonkey will give me the needed pid.

How do I combine that with os -o rss to give the memory used ?

Comment: System monitor must display that

Comment: Editing my post. I wanted it via cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ps`:

```
-q pidlist  
    Select by PID (quick mode).
    This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist.
```

To combine this with `ps -o rss`, use command subtitution:

```
ps -o rss -q $(pidof seamonkey)
```

Or the old-fashioned style with backquotes:

```
ps -o rss -q `pidof seamonkey`
```

You may want to add `--no-headers` if you are only interested in getting the number.